# Parsing text with sed / awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, sh

I am trying to parse an html table in order to obtain the values. See here.

```
    <tr>
            <th>CLI:</th>
            <td>0044123456789</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <th>Call Type:</th>
            <td>New Enquiry</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <th class=3D"nopaddingtop">Caller's Name:</th>
            <td class=3D"nopaddingtop">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <th class=3D"nopaddingmid"></th>
            <td class=3D"nopaddingmid">Mr</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <th class=3D"nopaddingmid"></th>
            <td class=3D"nopaddingmid">Lee</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <th class=3D"nopaddingbot"></th>
            <td class=3D"nopaddingbot">Butler</td>
    </tr>
```

I want to read the values associated wit the "CLI", "Call Type", and "Caller's Name" into separate variables using sed / awk.

For example:

```
cli="0044123456789"
call_type="New Enquiry"
caller_name="Mr Lee Butler"
```

How can I do this?

Many thanks, Neil.

Comment: If it's valid HTML I recommend to use an XML-Parser like `xmllint`.

Comment: agree about using XML-Parser, but not clear if you want to just find  `CLI` (etc) or the value(s) associated (`0044123456789`) ? Please update your question, rather than answering as a comment. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

One example for `CLI` one :

```
var=$(xmllint --html --xpath '//th[contains(., "CLI")]/../td/text()' file.html)
echo "$var"
```

For the multi `<tr>` part :

```
$ for key in {4..6}; do
    xmllint \
        --html \
        --xpath "//th[contains(., 'CLI')]/../../tr[$key]/td/text()" file.html
    printf ' '
done
echo
```

Output:

```
Mr Lee Butler
```

Comment: Hello - Thank you. This works for "cli" and "call_type" but not for "caller name". Any ideas? Many thanks, Neil.

Comment: It works, but in HTML `&nbsp;` is a space, so `xmllint` displays a space

Comment: Hi, it only outputs "Mr". It does not output the rest of the name "Lee Butler". Regards, Neil.

Comment: Hi, yes, I know. Unfortunately I have no control over the quality of the source data. :-( It arrives in an email. I have to strip the headers and footers to get the "html". Then I have to parse the "html" in order to obtain the values.

Comment: Added a solution for multiple `<tr>` lines